# Chaining webdriver methods

Tags: php, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to implement a class to carry out some common webdriver functions, but I keep getting: **the driver server has died.**

Something like this:

```
class mywebdriver {

    function __construct( $args ){

        //options
        $options = new ChromeOptions();
        $options->addArguments($args);

        //capabilities
        $caps = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
        $caps->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
        $driver = ChromeDriver::start($caps);
        $driver->manage()->timeouts()->implicitlyWait = 20;

        $this->driver = $driver;    
    }

    function login(){       
        //all things related to logging into a site using $this->driver
        $this->driver->get( "www.url.com" );
    }

    function logout(){      
        //all things related to logging into a site using $this->driver
        $this->driver->quit();
    }

    function search( $value ){      
        //enter a value in the search field and print results
    }

    ... other methods
}
```

Then, chaining the methods, such as:

```
$drive = new mywebdriver();
try {
    $drive->login()
        ->search( "toyota" )
        ->search( "ford" )
        ->logout();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught Exception". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Is this typical, and possible? I've tried a few things, but the driver server keeps giving me that "died" exception.

Answer (score 0):

To implement a method chain pattern, just return the instance like that:

```
public function search( $value ) : mywebdriver
{      
    //enter a value in the search field and print results
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: That's how most of my classes work, but the webdriver doesn't want to stay alive past the first method.. ideas?

Comment: @BenCoffin I don't understand what you mean. Further more when an instance isn't alive anymore, methods cannot be called on that at all (no matter whether or not chained).

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out if webdriver methods can be chained like that, or if they'll die before being returned from the first method. I was hoping somebody on stackoverflow has done (the above example) with webdriver and experienced the same exception, and knew why it doesn't seem to want to be chained.